# Cannot load an array with two for-loops?

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to build a simple array in JavaScript to be used later in a draw poker game. The array will old the string representations of the .jpg card values.

Currently there are two arrays that initialize the array so that the format will be

```
Example:    1h.jpg -- Ace
            2h.jpg -- two
```

h - heart
s - space
c - club
d - diamond

When I click on the load button on want the array to load and then print to the web page with the button on it, but currently it erases the current web page. I want to append it to the original web page. At some point I will use a Canvas to have the cards display in. The second section of the code is how I would like the if statement to be for loading an h,d,c,s to the string.

I really would like the if statement all in its own method to have a single line of code that would set the array index with the value and then return to the loadArray method. I am unfamiliar with JavaScript in how it passes the arrays back and forth between methods. I think that this array at some point will have to be global in JavaScript so that all of the methods that utilize it will have access.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadMyImageArray()">Load Image Array</button>    

<script>
    function loadMyImageArray() {
        var index = 1;
        var img = new Array();

        for (suit=0;suit<4;suit++)
        {
            for (card=1;card<=13;card++)
            {
                imgArray[index] = card.toString() + suit.toString() + ".jpg";
                document.writeln("Your Card is: " + img[index].toString());
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Code: (what i really want the IF statement to look like)

```
                 for (card=1;card<=13;card++)
        {
        document.writeln("Card: " +card);
            if(suit==1) {
        document.writeln("IF 1");       
                imgArray[index] = card.toString() + 'h' + ".jpg";
            } else if (suit==2) {
        document.writeln("IF 2");   
                imgArray[index] = card.toString() + 's' + ".jpg";
            } else if (suit==3) {
        document.writeln("IF 3");   
                imgArray[index] = card.toString() + 'd' + ".jpg";
            } else if (suit==4) {
        document.writeln("IF 4");   
                imgArray[index] = card.toString() + 'c' + ".jpg";
            }
```

New Code: (This is what I have for new code, have not yet appending the items to the original page)

```
      function loadMyImageArray() {
    var index = 1;
    var imgArray = new Array();
    var suits = ["h","s","d","c"];

    for (suit=0;suit<4;suit++)
    {
        for (card=1;card<=13;card++)
        {
            imgArray[index] = card + suits[suit] + ".jpg";
            document.writeln("Your Card is: " + imgArray[index].toString());
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `writeln`, it will overwrite you current page because it automatically calls `document.open` and clears your loaded, closed document. Use `createElement` and `appendChild` to add nodes to the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from your `imgArray` typo that J.P. has point out and using `writeln` which you shouldn't do, I think what you are trying to do is map the suit integer to a letter to construct your file name. In that case, it's easy. Just use an array!

```
var suits = ["h","s","d","c"];

for (suit=0;suit<4;suit++)
{
    for (card=1;card<=13;card++)
    {
         imgArray[index++] = card + suits[suit] + ".jpg";
    }
}
```

If you are trying to use `writeln` just for debugging purposes, use `console.log` instead which will echo to your debug console (in a lot of browsers, `f12` opens the console).

Here's a fiddle that I think does what you are trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/EmTWS/

Answer (score 2):

`imgArray` is not defined. It should be `img`

Also, use Chrome and open Dev Tools. That syntax error would have appeared in the console.

Comment: I just tried that and I did not see where it shows the error. That is with the F12 key and then there is a screen at the bottom that will show the message where you can expand the page and look at the different content.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to build an array that looks like this:
["1h.jpg", "2h.jpg" ... "12d.jpg", "13d.jpg"]

Then you can use this function:

```
function loadMyImageArray() {
        var index = 0;
        var suits = ['h', 's', 'c', 'd'];
        var imgArray = new Array(52);

        for (suit=0;suit<4;suit++)
        {
            for (card=1;card<=13;card++)
            {
                imgArray[index] = card.toString() + suits[suit] + ".jpg";
                index++;
            }
        }
        return imgArray
    }
```

In my console I get:

```
loadMyImageArray()
["1h.jpg", "2h.jpg", "3h.jpg", "4h.jpg", "5h.jpg", "6h.jpg", "7h.jpg", "8h.jpg", "9h.jpg", "10h.jpg", "11h.jpg", "12h.jpg", "13h.jpg", "1s.jpg", "2s.jpg", "3s.jpg", "4s.jpg", "5s.jpg", "6s.jpg", "7s.jpg", "8s.jpg", "9s.jpg", "10s.jpg", "11s.jpg", "12s.jpg", "13s.jpg", "1c.jpg", "2c.jpg", "3c.jpg", "4c.jpg", "5c.jpg", "6c.jpg", "7c.jpg", "8c.jpg", "9c.jpg", "10c.jpg", "11c.jpg", "12c.jpg", "13c.jpg", "1d.jpg", "2d.jpg", "3d.jpg", "4d.jpg", "5d.jpg", "6d.jpg", "7d.jpg", "8d.jpg", "9d.jpg", "10d.jpg", "11d.jpg", "12d.jpg", "13d.jpg"]
```

Comment: Is the console the page or is there an actual console in Google Chrome somewhere? I am new to web development.